# Dubai Terminal 3

Tags: airport-transfer, dubai, family, emirates

Hi I am arriving into Dubai on an emirates 777 flight from Newcastle and connecting onto an Emirates A380 flight to singapore. I am just wondering how long the connection time would be (travelling with kids) and also if there is a lounge I could book (by paying) which is near the departing gate?

Comment: One official source is http://www.dubaiairports.ae/ or check Emirates web page https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/emirates-terminal-3/facilities.aspx

Comment: Lounge access passes come for 100+$. Per Person. It might be cheaper to check in an in-the-airport-hotel.